# Uploading file to certain url based on file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, slack, slack-api

I am developing a system to upload to Slack Channel via bots but I have issue that I need to get a report being posted to certain channel.

How it works :

> I request all the report one by one on a loop and the report from the
>   server generates a pattern [UNIT_CODE]_ReportName_Date.pdf, I need to
>   upload it to different Slack Channel based on the UNIT CODE.
>
> MX001 = Unit A 
>   MH001 = Unit B 
>   MX002 = Unit C 
>   etc.

I am developing on Windows and I thought of using **Batch File, Task Schedulers and Curl** to upload the file on certain time.

I thought of the simplest idea using IFs but it would be a disaster if the units are too many and will be long to execute.

Any idea of the batch file would be fine because I am not quite good with doing loops with batch files.

I have a code sample that is halfway done because I am stuck with how can I upload the file in a loop :

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,5) DO (
  for %%x in (*.pdf) do (
   set file=""
   curl -J -O -L http://192.168.241.57:57328/Slack/ReceiveDataSingleLocation/%%A
   set "file=%%~nx"
   echo We're working with %file%
   curl -F file=@%file%.pdf -F channels=#hotel -F token=xx https://slack.com/api/files.upload
   del %file%.pdf
  )
)
```

Comment: Do not assign the FOR variable to an environmental variable. Just use the FOR variable directly with your commands.

Comment: files.upload has a rate limit of 20 calls per minute. If you have more files than that I would recommend adding a 3 seconds sleep after every API call. Otherwise you will get API errors.

Comment: Another point: API calls will not always succeed. So I would rather use a queue with a worker that can retry again after errors. Depends on how business critical those uploads are of course.